# Релиз WEBGL(Unity) проекта на сервер

Tags: unity3d, сервер, webgl, ftp-сервер

Есть сервер. 
Хочу на нём развернуть WebGL проект из Unity.
Как правильно это сделать? Может есть какие-то полезные статьи, гайды?

Answer (score 0):

Стоит прочитать основную документацию конечно. В ней вы найдете основыные гайды по сэтапу. [Официальная документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-building.html)
Так же. Рекомендую ознакомится с этими ссылками они вероятно могут быть полезны: [Гайд 1](https://habrahabr.ru/company/plarium/blog/312318/) и [Гайд 2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/281428/)